# tkinter .after() function is not pausing

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

When I try to run my code everything executes but the after function calls update immediately, despite the 5 second delay I put in. On top of this, the gui does not show any graph.

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import time
import functools

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

main = tk.Tk()
container = tk.Frame(main)
container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=main)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

def update(a, canvas):
        data = np.genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',', names=['x', 'y'])
        a.clear()
        a.plot(data['x'], data['y'], color='r', label='the data')


        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        print ("update")
        main.after(5000, functools.partial(update, a)(canvas))

main.after(5000, functools.partial(update, a)(canvas))
main.mainloop()
```

Any help on solving this issue or just general python tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why have you used import time? Time.sleep does not work in tkinter.

Comment: I was just using that for debugging and forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this line of code:

```
main.after(5000, functools.partial(update, a)(canvas))
```

It is doing exactly the same thing as this:

```
func = functools.partial(update, a)
result = func(canvas)
main.after(5000, result)
```

In order for `after` to do its job you must give it a *reference* to the function to be called. In your code you're actually calling it immediately and then passing the result to `after`.

Since you can supply positional arguments to `after` which will get passed on to your command, you can rewrite your `after` like this:

```
main.after(5000, functools.partial(update, a), canvas)
```

Though, I don't quite see why you think you need `functools.partial`. You should be able to condense it down to this:

```
main.after(5000, update, a, canvas)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I implemented your changes and they worked very well. The gui is not updating still but after seems to be working very well. Thanks again.